# Save dictionary on runtime as python code not using pickle

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I've a dictionary loaded in a variable as follows

```
>>constellation_dict["AND"]
array([[  2.35357132e+01,   3.51897736e+01],
       [  2.34684925e+01,   3.51880264e+01],
       [  2.34012642e+01,   3.51860695e+01],
       [  2.33340359e+01,   3.51838989e+01],
       [  2.32668228e+01,   3.51815186e+01],
       ....
       [  2.36029453e+01,   3.51913109e+01]])
```

Dictionary has arround 88 keys and each value consts of an arrays of tenths of pairs. All data is invariable (correspond to constellations border)

Currently I can load (and eventualy save it) with pickle methods. My question is:  Is there any way to store it as python code or similar so I can load it as module part and not having to read a file every time I call the module?

I tried to use json module to turn it into simple code but it says that "object is not serializable".

By the way, these are the methods I'm using currently to load/save dictionary

```
import pickle
def save_obj(obj, name, protocol = pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL):
    with open('obj/'+ name + '.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        #posible alternative protocol 0 (text_format)
        pickle.dump(obj, f, protocol)

def load_obj(name ):
    with open('obj/' + name + '.pkl', 'r') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)

constellation_dictionary = load_obj('const_dict.dat')
```

Comment: That's not a dictionary, that's a Numpy array at best.

Comment: You have no dictionary there and I wonder what are you calling 'key' and 'value'...

Comment: Since you're just trying to turn it into Python interpretable code, why don't you just do `str(constellation_dictionary)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fromfile and tofile (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html). It's easy and fast.

Other option is create a module with the dictionary inside as a variable, like:
data.py:

```
consmap = {'AND' : [[....]],
            ...
           'OTHERKEY' : [[]]}
```

and in other module:

```
from data import consmap
print consmap['AND']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an alternative to `pickle` or `json`, you can use `klepto`.

```
>>> init = {'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
>>> import klepto
>>> cache = klepto.archives.file_archive('memo', init, serialized=False)
>>> cache        
{'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
>>>
>>> # dump dictionary to the file 'memo.py'
>>> cache.dump() 
>>> 
>>> # import from 'memo.py'
>>> from memo import memo
>>> print memo
{'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
```

With `klepto`, if you had used `serialized=True`, the dictionary would have been written to `memo.pkl` as a pickled dictionary instead of with clear text (as importable python code).

You can get `klepto` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/klepto

You can configure `klepto` to store dictionaries to a file, to a directory context, or to a SQL database.  The API is the same for whatever you choose as the backend archive.  It gives you an "archivable" dictionary with which you can use `load` and `dump` to interact with the archive.  You can also choose the storage format, where `klepto` can be configured to store your data with `pickle` or with `json` or as a string, or as a hash, or several other methods for encoding the key and value in the persistent store.